# The second input replaces the last characters of the first input in scanf and fgets

Tags: c

I am trying to take a string input in C and I have tried both `scanf` and `fgets` for the same. However, one weird thing that is happening is that when I take a large input in first string, and then press enter and enter the second string, the second string replaces the characters at the end of the first string. This is happening with both `fgets` and `scanf`. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

#define MAX_SIZE 10000  // Added in the edit

int main() {
  char* str1;
  char* str2;
  char* deleted;
  int len1, len2;

  str1 = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(MAX_SIZE)));
  str2 = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(MAX_SIZE)));
  deleted = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(MAX_SIZE)));

  fgets (str1, MAX_SIZE, stdin);
  fgets (str2, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

  printf(" - %s - %d \n", str1, len1);
  printf(" - %s - %d \n", str2, len2);
}
```

Here is the output :

```
$ ./a.out 
qwertyuiolkjhgfdsazxcvbnmSTACK
OVERFLOW
 - qwertyuiolkjhgfdOVERFLOW     <<<<<< The second string gets appended in the first
 - 25 
 - OVERFLOW
 - 9
```

Comment: sorry @melpomene .. I had defined it but forgot to add it here

Comment: `sizeof(MAX_SIZE)` is nonsense.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(MAX_SIZE))` --> `malloc(MAX_SIZE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `#define MAX_SIZE 10000`

then

`str1 = (char*)(malloc(sizeof(MAX_SIZE)));` // <-- wrong

What you need is:

`str1 = malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));`

---

Also, you have `deleted` variable that is never used.

And remember `fgets` has `\n` at the end that is usually removed by using `strcspn` ([Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input))

`str1[strcspn(str1, "\n")] = 0;`

---

Finally, you are using `len1`, `len2` completely uninitialised, this caused undefined behaviour. What you need is:

`printf(" - %s - %zu \n", str1, strlen(str1));`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Comment: @melpomene yes, it's just to clarify intention